# Tenorflow small objects far from camera detection

Tags: api, tensorflow, object-detection

I am using the tensorflow object detection API for the object detection task. However, I have objects that are captured from a high angle (camera at 10 m) and in a very small size where the size of images is 1920 x 1080.

Questions:

1) What is the best way to detect small objects under this condition?

2) What are the features of suitable dataset? Images from the same views (maybe!)?

I appreciate all of your answers, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to consider object detector's input size, even if you use high resolution image such as 1920x1080.

Because object detector resize input image to their architecture size(ex. general YOLO use 410x410 input in their architecture)

On the other hand, if you use 1920x1080 image as it is, your API will resize it to small resolution like 410x410.

It means your small objects in images will be disappeared during passing through convolution filter.

In my opinion,

1) If you know where small objects is located in whole image, CROP&SEPARATE image and USE as an input image.

Even though you do not know where small objects is, you can make several candidate list that is separated by some method.

2) I don't understand what you want to know, please let me know more specific.

Comment: Thanks, @Roy Lee. To train my model I use the pre-trained checkpoints from https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md, my training dataset should be the same size as the model gets?

Comment: I am wondering what is the best way to train my model? images for training must be at what size?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try "faster_rcnn_resnet101" model with kitti dataset, this has the max image size of 1987. but this model is very slow compared to any other SSD models. The configuration link is below -

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/001a2a61285e378fef5f45386f638cb5e9f153c7/research/object_detection/samples/configs/faster_rcnn_resnet101_kitti.config

Also the Faster rcnn models do better job compared to yolo in small object detection, not sure of performance with ssd model.